# Why won't while loop exit?

Tags: c++

I'm making a program that collects student names and grades from the user into vectors and uses the vectors to calculate the average. When the user types "done" the while loop is supposed to break and move on to the next piece of code. However, the while loop I've made won't break. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

I've tried creating a bool that breaks when bool is true but still did not work.

```
while (name != "done") {
     cout << "Enter name and grade: ";
     cin >> name;

     if (!(cin >> score)) {
          cin.clear;
          cin.ignore(256, '\n');
          cout << "Re-enter grade: ";
          cin >> score;
     }

     else {
          studentName.push_back(name);
          studentScore.push_back(score);
     }
}
```

The while loop is supposed to exit when "done" is typed but instead it creates a newline and does not output anything.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Have you tried stepping through the code with a debugger and inspecting the variable to see exactly why the loop is not exiting? Using a debugger is an essential skill for any programmer to have. StackOverflow is not a debugging service.

Comment: How is name variable defined? Is it a `std::string`? Is it a `char*`? You cannot compare strings or char* with `!=` or `==`. If it is a `std::string`, you need to execute compare string functions `(name.compare( "done"))` or `strcmp` functions if it is a `char*`

Comment: use break inside loop with condition name == "done"

Comment: your code doesn't compile, please provide a [mre]

Comment: @SuperG280 actually std::string provides an overload of `==` (and such) to compare szring-objects with cstrings

Answer (score 0):

When you type "done", the rest of the loop is still executed, since you just check at the beginning. So, it expects you to input the score next and would exit after that.

One possible solution would be to insert a `break`-statement right after reading `name`

```
if(name == "done") {
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve your problem easily by replacing the while(){} with a do{ }while()

So you code becomes

```
do{
     cout << "Enter name and grade: ";
     cin >> name;

     if (!(cin >> score)) {
          cin.clear;
          cin.ignore(256, '\n');
          cout << "Re-enter grade: ";
          cin >> score;
     }

     else {
          studentName.push_back(name);
          studentScore.push_back(score);
     }
}while (name != "done");
```